# Workaround for :disabled:valid CSS issue

Tags: html, css

I have some fields that have placeholders and also labels.  The labels are hidden until text is entered.  When text is in the input box, then the label shows (since the placeholder is now hidden)

The way I implemented this in CSS is to use the :valid selector.  I make each input have "required", and then :valid triggers whenever that input has text

```css
.fstyle{font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#000}
.fstyle .fbutton{width:50%;margin:18px auto;background-color:#ef8f34;opacity:.5;color:#fff;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;text-align:center;padding:15px 5px;font-size:20px;font-weight:700;overflow:visible;margin-bottom:7px;text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);-webkit-transition:.5s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;-o-transition:.5s ease-in-out;transition:.5s ease-in-out}
.fstyle .fbutton.active{opacity:1;cursor:pointer;-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px #888;-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px #888;box-shadow:2px 2px 3px #888}
.fstyle .fbutton.active:hover{background-color:#f29d51;text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);-webkit-transition:.2s;-moz-transition:.2s;-o-transition:.2s;transition:.2s}
.fstyle .finputbtn{display:inline-block;display:none;position:absolute;width:100px;margin:0 0 0 -100px;height:40px;line-height:40px;font-size:16px;color:#fff;background:#ef8f34;text-align:center;cursor:pointer!important}
.fstyle h4{font-size:13px;font-weight:700;color:#4d4d4d;display:block;width:auto;padding:18px 0 4px 4px;margin-bottom:12px;border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f}
.fstyle h3{font-size:16px;font-weight:700;color:#4d4d4d;display:block;width:auto;padding:18px 0 4px 4px;margin-bottom:12px;border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f}
.fstyle .select-contain{padding:0;margin:0 0 32px;border:2px solid #b7b7b7;width:auto;border-radius:0;overflow:hidden;color:#000;background:#e4e4e4 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAICAYAAADwdn+XAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAANRQAADUUBUfHEqAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAADKSURBVCiRfdA/L8NhFMXxzyOa+JPo3MQiNoLVIGKymkwGL8DLUhKJSFgNhs4MTUSYGbwA0qTkWB5NNb+6273ne0/uuQWr2MIr+kkG/qlSyjw2sYx+SaKU0sERFtBDL8nXxGILO9jFAN0kbyXJLzCHQ6zhGadJvqvWxjE6eMFFkk8YGVSwYB97eMIZFnGCJdzhNmNLfwzGjA6wjccaawX3SS4n2dkpv7pBG+u1f8d1EzjTNKwnXuEDQ5wnGTaxjRFGYikbaCV5mMb8AP68TeEXCmHVAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat 95% 50%}
.fstyle select{padding:11px 8px;width:130%;border:none;box-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;background-image:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none;font-size:14px}
.fstyle select:focus{outline:none}
.fstyle label{visibility: hidden;opacity:0;transition: visibility 0s ease-in-out .5s, opacity .5s ease-in-out;position:absolute;top:-12px;left:-2px;padding:2px 4px;margin:0;background:#fff;border:2px solid #b7b7b7;border-bottom:0;border-radius:10px 10px 10px 0;font-size:12px;color:#669}
.fstyle input:valid + label,.fstyle textarea:valid + label{visibility: visible;opacity:1;transition: opacity .5s ease 0s,visibility 0s ease-in-out 0s}
.fstyle .txtinput-contain{position:relative;padding:0;margin:0 0 32px;border:2px solid #b7b7b7;width:auto;border-radius:0;color:#000;background:#fff;text-align:left}

.fstyle .___-_{width:auto;text-align:right;position:relative}
.fstyle .___- {width:60%}
.fstyle    .-_{width:34%;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;margin:0}

.fstyle .__-__{width:auto;text-align:right;position:relative}
.fstyle .__-  {width:47%}
.fstyle   .-__{width:47%;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;margin:0}

.fstyle input{padding:12px 10px;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;border:none;box-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;background-image:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none;font-size:14px}
.fstyle input:focus{outline:none}
.fstyle input:disabled,.fstyle input:disabled:valid + label{background:#ddd;}
.fstyle textarea{padding:12px 10px;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;border:none;box-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;background-image:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none;font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;height:104px;resize:none}
.fstyle textarea:focus{outline:none}
.fstyle .val-box{font-size:12px;background:#d74b4b;color:#fff;padding:0;top:0;position:relative;margin-top:0;width:auto;opacity:0;height:0;transition:all .2s ease-out}
.fstyle input.isinvalid:not(:focus) ~ .val-box,.fstyle textarea.isinvalid:not(:focus) ~ .val-box{opacity:1;margin-top:-8px;padding:2px 8px;height:14px}
.fstyle .headimg{margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:15px;max-width:100%;max-height:auto}
.fstyle.cozy .select-contain,.fstyle.cozy .txtinput-contain{margin-bottom:14px}
```

```html
<div class='fstyle cozy'>
      <h4>Welcome, please set up your account</h4>
      <div class='txtinput-contain'>
        <input id="company" type='text' name='company' placeholder='Company / Organization' value="asdfasfdasdf" disabled required/>
        <label for='company'>Company</label>
        <div class='val-box'>Please enter your company name</div>
      </div>
      <div class='txtinput-contain'>
        <input id="username" class="isvalid" type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email / Login' required/>
        <label for='email'>Login</label>
        <div class='val-box'>Please enter a valid email</div>
      </div>
      <div class='__-__'>
        <div class='txtinput-contain __-'>
          <input id="name_f" type='text' name='firstname' placeholder='First name' required/>
          <label for='firstname'>First name</label>
          <div class='val-box'>Required</div>
        </div>
        <div class='txtinput-contain -__' >
          <input id="name_l" type='text' name='lastname' placeholder='Last name' required/>
          <label for='lastname'>Last name</label>
          <div class='val-box'>Required</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='__-__'>
        <div class='txtinput-contain __-'>
          <input id="password" type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' required/>
          <label for='password'>Password</label>
          <div class='val-box'>Password is too short</div>
        </div>
        <div class='txtinput-contain -__' >
          <input id="cpass" type='password' name='confirmpassword' placeholder='Confirm password' required/>
          <label for='confirmpassword'>Confirm password</label>
          <div class='val-box'>Password does not match</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h4>Tell us about you</h4>
      <div class='txtinput-contain'>
          <textarea name='message' placeholder='Describe your training needs' required></textarea>
          <label for='message'>About you</label>
          <div class='val-box'>Please briefly describe your training needs</div>
</div>
</div
```

Run the above to see it, and type into a field

If I make a field disabled, the field itself turns grey, but the label does not show (eg the field is disabled but there is text in it, I want the label to show what the text means).

I want it to show like this 
[image]

But instead it shows like this.
[image]

The line of css that is not working (you can see it in the snipped above)

```
.fstyle input:disabled,.fstyle input:disabled:valid + label{background:#ddd;}
```

I'm assuming that `input:disabled:valid` is the issue, but I don't know how to express it in CSS to get the same result

Edit:

This is the javascript/jquery "solution" to imitate what CSS should be doing. **It's truly terrible**, so I really hope there's a CSS solution.  And to clarify, form templates and their data are loaded separately, so the value of an input, and whether it is disabled can change any time.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.fstyle input:disabled').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()) {
            $(this).siblings('label').css({
               visibility: "visible",
               opacity: 1
            });
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('label').css({
               visibility: "hidden",
               opacity: 0
            });
        }
    });
},100);
```

Comment: works for me (Chrome 47) exactly as your "I want" picture.

Comment: @Christoph Try a different browser (it doesn't work in IE or Firefox, for example).

Comment: Disabled input fields are not submittable, and as such they aren’t “candidates for constraint validation” – so `input:disabled:valid` does not make sense as a selector – a disabled field can not be valid or invalid. // In [this similar attempt](http://thatemil.com/blog/2016/01/23/floating-label-no-js-pure-css/) the author is using the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo class to determine whether an element is empty or not; but that doesn’t seem to have great browser support as of now. (It’s part of CSS 4, I think.)

Comment: @Siguza Really? Because Firefox 44 (latest stable) shows the square result without the "Company" label. Same in 43.0.4, too.

Comment: Confirming @CBroe's comment: it works with when adding `input:disabled + label` after the `input:valid + label` CSS rule you have.

Comment: In fact in Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m and 48.0.2564.82 m both on Win7, it also doesn't show the Company label @Christoph what version exactly of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @Christoph In case I wasn't clear, it does work perfectly when the field IS NOT disabled.  But when it's disabled, the label doesn't show. I'm using chrome on windows and linux

Comment: @CBroe  That's right, I understand and I think it's reasonable. But it seems there must be another (supported) way.  I never really liked the :valid hack anyways since what I'm after is like a :has-content selector or a :not([value=""]) type thing

Comment: If the field is `disabled`, then I suppose at the time you disable it you already know whether it will have a value or not? In that case, I’d just add an additional class then, and format the following label accordingly using that class …

Comment: Yes, I realized that, after you changed your code example slightly and the disabled field turned up;) So yes, not working is chrome as well, and I have no idea on how to solve without additional classes... :-/

Comment: @AwokeKnowing what about this `.fstyle input[disabled]:not([value='']) + label{...}` ? I tried in chrome and firefox and seems working for me

Comment: @CBroe that's certainly the "javascript" solution.  but what I'm after is a CSS solution so that in javascript can just worry about whether it's disabled or what value it has,  and the CSS will style it, as it should be.  Previously I was actually showing and hiding the labels in  javascript, but moved to this css-only solution, except for this case.  I don't want to have to remember to add javascript to add a "force-label" class any time I set a field (with text) to disabled.

Comment: @nik if that works I wouldn't even need a special case for disabled, I can just show/hide the label based on [value=''"] always.  Is that ie11+ Chrome +FF +Safari compatible? Also will it work whether the field value is null or ""?

Comment: @nik: `:not([value=''])` won’t work for fields where the value is changed later on via script (non-empty to empty, or vice versa) – because setting it via script will only set the `value` _property_, not the _attribute_.

Comment: @CBroe yeah right, may be in that case instead of setting value, it should be set as a attribute value, e.g. in jquery `.attr("value", "abc")`

Comment: @AwokeKnowing `:not` (basic) selector is supported in almost most of browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: @nik I'm concerned more about the [value=""] and also whether it works the same for textarea

Comment: No, it won’t work for `textarea`, because textarea doesn’t have a `value` attribute in HTML (that you use the `.value` property to fill a textarea via script, is a different issue.) And it won’t work for an input field that doesn’t have a value attribute set either – it won’t match `<input>`, only `<input value>` or `<input value="">`, although they of course all “look” the same.

Comment: @CBroe I was thinking maybe the :empty selector might work, eg textarea:not(:empty) but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: `textarea:not(:empty)` should work in theory; in Chrome it does, can’t test other browsers right now.

Comment: @CBroe `textarea:not(:empty)` is not working for me, at least in the case of starting empty and then typing text into the field.

Comment: Yeah, that is again the same issue as with the mentioned setting of input value via script … typing into the textarea doesn’t actually change the DOM structure, it does not make the textarea have a (text) child node – but the selection via `:empty` is based on the DOM structure.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the issue with disabled inputs, you will run into other problems such as if you decide to use `<input type="email" />` - the label will stop showing up if the input is not a `:valid` email address.

Unfortunately something like this is going to be outside the scope of CSS. There are plenty of clever tricks to make it "somewhat" work, but for it to work properly you will need to use JavaScript.

Since your (now deleted) sample answer uses jQuery, I'll likewise use jQuery to simplify the example, but of course it can be achieved in vanilla JavaScript easily enough.

```
$(document.body).on("input change", ".fstyle input", function(e) {
    var input = $(this),
        label = input.next("label");

    if( input.val()) label.addClass("hastext");
    else label.removeClass("hastext");
});
// trigger for initial state:
$(".fstyle input").trigger("change");
```

Then use the `.hastext` class to define how the label should be displayed when the input has text.

This avoids restricting the HTML5 validation you can do, and should work reasonably well.

Comment: I'm not sure change or input events trigger when you change the value of a disabled field.  But in any case, your point about type=email is true, though I don't use it for several reasons. But in any case, if there is a CSS solution, like [value=''] or :not(:empty) etc, it would also take care of the fact that I'm using :valid.   I'm still hoping for a CSS solution